# MAMP upgrade - can't access existing database

Tags: mamp

After a clean install of Mojave (MacOS) and MAMP, I tried to transfer my old MAMP **db** folder to new installation. This had worked with previous updates but NOT this time.

I suspect the new versions are significantly different.
Previously was using MAMP v4 (?) on Mavericks. The relevant database folder was called **mysql** and noted that the new folder is called **mysql57**.

So I renamed the NEW folder so I could step back if things didn't work. 
Then started up MAMP and was prompted to update the database – clicked YES.

**What is the best way forward?**
I have the old db folder on ext HDD still and sql backups of the the old tables. Did the data/tables need to be updated to a more intermediary version of MAMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**. CHECK the PHP version (MAMP Preferences)... I had to change mine from 7.2.10 to 7.1.22 (standard) to resolve the problem.